# Javascript HTML Registration

Tags: javascript, html, forms, registration

I am creating a html document for class and there is an example in my notes that is very similar to what I have to do it has First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number, my question is what does this line of code mean? There is a .addphone in style but the code on the bottom only applies to phone why not first name or last name?

```
        <!-- <div class="addphone" onclick="addPhone();">Add Phone</div> -->
    <input id="adduser" type="submit" value="Add User" style="margin-top: 25px;">
 </div>
```

Comment: ... _Which_ line, exactly?  I guessed the first line.

Comment: Is the code on the bottom, or on the button?

Comment: @Kevin I'd say Homer was referring to `class="addphone"` and "style" means CSS. What "the code on the bottom" is is anyone's guess. Same for "registration".

Answer (score 1):

Why not first name or last name?

I guess it's because your 'user' can have more than one phone, but not more than one first name or last name.  This isn't really a programming question then though, is it?!

It's never good to put an `onclick()` event handler on a `div` element.  It also looks like the `div` has been given a class for styling to make it look like a button or link.  Well, if you need a button, or link, then use a button, or link.  That way, keyboard support is automatically included.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of code is an example of a clickable element. In this case has been commented out, meaning it will not be rendered in the browser.

For example:

```
<!-- Anything written here won't affect the page -->
```

Is it possible this line, plus the line in your stylesheet, are examples on how to write your other fields for your assignement?